# User Input filename open file

Tags: c++, file, filenames

(Solved)(I don't know how to close it)I'm trying to accept user input to open up a .dat file that's in my source files but I don't know why the file keeps failing to open. I've already checked syntax and other things but I just can't find the solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "arrayFunctions.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string fileName;
   int size = 0;
   ifstream inputFile;
   do
   {
      cout << "Please enter file name: ";
      getline(cin,fileName);

      inputFile.open(fileName.c_str());
      if (!inputFile)
      {
         cout << "The file \"" << fileName << "\" failed to open.\n"
              << "Check to see if the file exists and please try again" 
              << endl << endl;
      }
      while (inputFile.good())
      {
          string stop = " ";
          string num;
          getline(inputFile, stop);
          size++;
      }
    } while (!inputFile);

    cout << size << endl << endl;
    inputFile.close();

    system("pause");
}
```

the problem seems to lie in actually opening the file because this fails

```
do
{
    ifstream inputFile("num.txt");
    opened = true;
    if (!inputFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "The file \"" << fileName << "\" failed to open.\n"
             << "Check to see if the file exists and please try again" 
             << endl << endl;
        opened = false;
    }
    inputFile.close();
} while (!opened);
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is where it should be?  For example if the user enters foo.txt the foo.txt file would have to be wherever the working directory for the process is

Comment: @Jerry Jerehmiah Apparently I needed to move the file to actual source code folder rather than dragging it to source code folder on microsoft visual studio. I select yours as the answer but its a comment

Comment: Just accept an Answer(if correct) or write your Own answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that `inputFile` is an object defined on the stack, so putting that directly into an if statement probably isn't doing what you think it's doing - it's always going to be a reference to an object, and will never be null.

I'm not too sure what happens if you implicitly convert an ifstream to a boolean.

Try changing this

```
if (!inputFile)
```

<strike>to</strike>

```
if (!inputFile.is_open())
```

I've brushed up on the reference for streams, specifically what the [good()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/) method does. Effectively it's too broad for you to deduce what's going wrong - it could be a hard disk error, a permissions error, the wrong file name, etc.

You'll get a clearer picture of what's going on if you display an error message using something like this (adapted from the C++ reference):

```
if (!inputFile.good()) {
  cout << "The file \"" << fileName << "\" failed to open.\n"
  cout << "good()=" << inputFile.good();
  cout << " eof()=" << inputFile.eof();
  cout << " fail()=" << inputFile.fail();
  cout << " bad()=" << inputFile.bad();
}
```

Comment: that didn't work. But the ifstream provides functions like good and fail which I tried with the same result. It seems the file doesnt open

Comment: @Darr Brett I realized I my mistake was due to visual studio not moving the file to its directory when I dragged it to source code folder in the solution explorer. I had to move the file in the file explorer itself. Regardless its useful to know /i can do that with the errors